# motif finder in a text file using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have a big text file like this example:

example:

```
>chr9:128683-128744
GGATTTCTTCTTAGTTTGGATCCATTGCTGGTGAGCTAGTGGGATTTTTTGGGGGGTGTTA
>chr16:134222-134283
AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG
>chr16:134226-134287
GGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGACGGCCGATTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGGATTT
>chr1:134723-134784
AAGTGATTCACCCTGCCTTTCCGACCTTCCCCAGAACAGAACACGTTGATCGTGGGCGATA
>chr16:135770-135831
GCCTGAGCAAAGGGCCTGCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTT
```

this file is divided into different parts and every part has 2 rows. the 1st row starts with `>` (and this row is called ID) and the 2nd row is the sequence of letters.
I want to search for a short motif (`GGAC`) in the sequence of letters and if they contain the motif, I want to get the the ID of that line (which is one row above that).

for the above example, here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
>chr16:134222-134283
>chr16:134226-134287
```

I am trying to do that in python using the following command but it does not return what I want.

```
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
ss = 'CCGA'
new = []
for line in range(len(infile)):
    if not infile[line].startswith('>'):
        for match in pattern.finder(ss):
            new.append(infile[line-1])
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is "pattern.finder" ??? And how does your code "not return what you want" ?

Answer (score 6):

It will be more robust and simpler to use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) for this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

motif = 'GGAC'
for record in SeqIO.parse('input.fa', 'fasta'):
    if motif in record.seq:
        print(record.id)
```

Comment: `record.seq.upper()` for a case in-sensitive search

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator might be convenient here.

```
def find_motif(f, motif):
    while True:
        try:
            id_line = next(f)
            text_line = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        if motif in text_line:
            yield id_line

with open("my file") as f:
    with_motif = find_motif(f, "ABCD")
    for id_line in with_motif:
        print(id_line)
```

So:

```
text = """>chr9:128683-128744
GGATTTCTTCTTAGTTTGGATCCATTGCTGGTGAGCTAGTGGGATTTTTTGGGGGGTGTTA
>chr16:134222-134283
AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG
>chr16:134226-134287
GGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGACGGCCGATTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGGATTT
>chr1:134723-134784
AAGTGATTCACCCTGCCTTTCCGACCTTCCCCAGAACAGAACACGTTGATCGTGGGCGATA
>chr16:135770-135831
GCCTGAGCAAAGGGCCTGCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTT"""
f = iter(text.splitlines())

with_motif = find_motif(f, "GGAC")
for id_line in with_motif:
    print(id_line)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>chr16:134222-134283
>chr16:134226-134287
```

Comment: you cannot know from the question, but the assume of one header line and one sequence line is wrong for FASTA format in general

Comment: That could be the case, but the description stated _this file is divided into different parts and every part has 2 rows. the 1st row starts with > (and this row is called ID) and the 2nd row is the sequence of letters._

Comment: the description is wrong unfortunately in failing to describe the file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's always better to use parsers from dedicated libraries in these cases.